# Remove dynamically added li via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a `<ul>` which add `<li>` dynamically by a button with a remove button.

Initially the default li must not contain a remove so i added it in script

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function () 
{       
  $('.main').append('<br>');    
  $('.main').append($('.append_list').html());

  $('.main').append("<button class='rmv_btn' style='clear:both'> Remove </button>");

});                 
$(".rmv_btn").click(function () 
{
   $(this).remove("append_list");
  //Also tried this      $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
});
```

When i click the remove button that particular section only removed.....

**HTML**

```
     <ul class="main" style="list-style-type:none;">
<li class="append_list">
  <label>Product 1</label> <input type="text">
  <br>
   <label>Product 2</label> <input type="text">
  <br>
   <label>Product 3</label> <input type="text">
  <br>
   <label>Product 4</label> <input type="text">
  <br>

</li>
</ul>
<button id="add" style="clear:both">ADD NEW PRODUCTS</button>-
```

Here I made a [bin](http://jsbin.com/unaxon/4/) in this.

How can i make this??

**NOTE**

I have made this process but till its complecated for i want to place the remove button next to the first textbox created here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function () 
{       
    $('.main').append($('.main > :first-child').clone());
    $('.main').append("<button class='rmv_btn' style='clear:both'> Remove </button>");

});                 
$('.main').on("click",".rmv_btn",function () 
{   $(this).prev('li').remove();
     $(this).remove();
});
});​
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MpEUZ/1/)

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MpEUZ/3/)

Comment: This works fine dude. But when i use `clone()` all values of previous text boxes also cloned here

Comment: @VivekDragon you will have to remove the values before cloning..wait a sec i will edit it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** for binding event on dynmically added controls. You also need to append the button in added `li` instead of adding in the rool of `ul`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/unaxon/16/edit)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $('.main').append('<br>');
        $('.main').append($('.append_list :first').clone());
        $('.main li:last').append("<button class='rmv_btn' style='clear:both'> Remove </button>")
        $('.main li:last :input').val('');
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".rmv_btn", function() {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();

    });
});​
```

Comment: In the above demo when the first added li is removed then its completely not working friend....

Comment: Friend the clone() copies all the above values in textbox to next boxes. Is there a way to avoid it???

Answer (score 1):

use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).`on` attachs an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
$(document).on('click',".rmv_btn",function ()
 .....
```

**UPDATED**

the code was appending elements inside `<li>` so your newly added elements was missing the `<li>` ... u need to append the element inside the `<ul class=main>` so that the added elements is wrapped inisde `<li>`

```
$("#add").click(function () {           
 //$('.main').append('<br>');
   $('ul.main').append($(".main").html());
   $('.main li:last').append("<button class='rmv_btn' style='clear:both'> Remove </button>");   
}); 

$(document).on("click", ".rmv_btn", function () 
{
   $(this).closest('li').remove(); // and add the closet() to remove to closest <li>

});​
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zVgm/1/)..

Answer (score 1):

One solution could just be attaching the remove function directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $('.main').append("<div><br />" + $('.append_list').html() + '<button class="rmv_btn" onclick="$(this.parentNode).remove()">Remove</button></div>');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/unaxon/11)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I want to throw this one in, without the need for [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbXsX/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="main" style="list-style-type:none;">
<li class="append_list">
    <label>Product 1</label> <input type="text">   <br>
    <label>Product 2</label> <input type="text">   <br>
    <label>Product 3</label> <input type="text">   <br>
    <label>Product 4</label> <input type="text">   <br>
</li>
</ul>
<button style="clear:both" onclick="add_products()">ADD NEW PRODUCTS</button>-
```

JS:

```
function remove_products(element) {
    $(element).prev().remove();
    $(element).remove();
}

function add_products() {
    $('.main').append($('.main > :first-child').clone());
    $('.main').append('<button style="clear:both" onclick="remove_products(this)"> Remove </button>');
}
```