# Positioning Dynamically created Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, positioning

I have created four text boxes and when I click a delete button it adds another set of text boxes with a remove button like this:

[image]

This is My script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $('.main').append("<div><br />" + $('.append_list').html() + '<button class="rmv_btn" onclick="$(this.parentNode).remove()">Remove</button></div>');
    });
});
```

How can I add this button next to the first text box which is created dynamically?

With reference to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14119764/1716774)

**Output Image**

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand. You want to place the remove button next to the first textbox of the page ?

Comment: @Magus pls check the updated image.....

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary container in which you insert your cloned input list. Then find the first input in that temp container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var container = $('<div />').addClass('justadded').appendTo('.main');
        $(container).append($('.append_list').html());
        var input = $(container).find('input:first');
        $('<button />').text("Remove").addClass('rmv_btn').attr('onclick', '$(this.parentNode).remove()').insertAfter(input);
        $(container).removeClass('justadded');
    });
});
```

Comment: without adding button after the li is there a way to add it inside the li content....

Comment: Sure, assuming your input fields are inside `<li></li>` elements and you want to append the button to the first li, replace the following: `var input = $(container).find('input:first');` with: `var input = $(container).find('li:first');`

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/MpEUZ/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    $('.main > :first-child').clone().appendTo('.main').find('input[type=text]').val('');
    $('.main .append_list:last').find('input[type=text]:first').after("<button class='rmv_btn' style='clear:both'> Remove </button>");

});
$('.main').on("click", ".rmv_btn", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});​
```

Comment: without adding button after the li is there a way to add it inside the li content....

Comment: Friend inspite of using the above code i would like to add the button inside the .append-list so that i can position it with css by position:absolute property. Is there any way to make this???

Answer (score 0):

This one should works :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var html = $($('.append_list').html());
        html.find('input').first().after('<button class="rmv_btn" onclick="$(this.parentNode).remove()">Remove</button></div>');

        $('.main').append("<div><br />" + html);
    });
});
```

I guess `$('.append_list')` is containing the good html for the inputs.

Comment: Which li ? I don't know your html structure so i can't really do anything.